# Comunication between server GRPC, NODE.JS with MYSQL and client Android

Tags: android, mysql, node.js, grpc

I'm trying to send and receive data like this:

Server node.js:

```
find: ({request: {id}}, callback) => { cn.executeQuery(`SELECT id, name FROM tb WHERE id=${id}`, (res) => callback(null, {result: res.result, unit: res.rows}));
```

and receive:

```
{
  result: 'ok',
  unit: [ { id: 1, name: 'Test' } ]
}
```

and the client (Android):

```
UnitServiceGrpc.UnitServiceBlockingStub stub = UnitServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(mChannel);

UnitFindRequest request = UnitFindRequest.newBuilder().setId(id).build();

UnitFindResponse reply = stub.find(request);

Unit response = reply.getUnit();
```

and receive:

```
com.test.ger.UnitFindResponse@1a1bf6a
                 unit {
                 }
```

How can I serialize the answer on server to pass the `.proto` Unit and receive it on client?

Comment: Are you using static or dynamic proto code generation? (https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/tree/master/examples/helloworld)

Comment: Dynamic, I can't get this.

Comment: I assume your proto object should be inside the `message` as in the example: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/blob/master/examples/helloworld/dynamic_codegen/greeter_server.js#L37